# What to do when you have an interdisciplinary question?

Tags: discussion

I'm a physics & mathematics student, and while doing mathematics regarding a physical theory, I'm trying to be rigorous as if I'm doing pure mathematics, and I'm an active user in this site.

However, whenever I have some question about physics, if I asked in [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com), I might or might not get an answer, and if I get, I will take some time. Plus, the number of users who will provide me an answer with a rigorous mathematics is really low as far as I see, so even I get an answer at some point, it might not be helpful (This is a general problem between me and my professors also).

However, if I ask in here on math.SE, the concept might not be generally known, so I need to provide lots of references for the concepts, and explain them. Plus, even if I do that, the question still might be closed because its if off-topic. Moreover, the answer at some point might contain experimental results, so asking directly in here might be problematic. Addition to that, after all if this is a physics question, you also want to learn what those mathematical results physically imply, so...

This is the general dilemma almost every time I have a physics question.

First of all, do you have any suggesting about what can I do ?

Secondly, I was thinking asking the question in one site, and opening a question in the other site for referencing that question, so that both "parties" can take a look to the question and maybe together they can provide a good answer from both physical and mathematical point of view.

Comment: Can you give some examples (e.g. some questions you asked here or in physics SE)?

Comment: @JohnMa I was very reluctant to ask those kind of question for a very long time, but I will check whether there is any one left that I haven't deleted.

Comment: @JohnMa This question might be an example https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/383974/how-to-mathematically-work-out-the-color-of-the-sky

Comment: It seems like if you can’t decide what discipline something falls under, it might be too general. The only sample you gave above seems like it clearly should be in physics. Not that nobody here could do it, it’s just that the question is more physics centric than mathematics. It’s not like we have to do all mathematics in this forum.

Comment: @rschwieb :) Yes, definitely we do not have to, but there are few users who does good job in answering question in a mathematically rigorous way, of course assuming you could find them.